# What is the difference between these worms: Caenorhabditis elegans and Eisenia fetida?

Tags: invertebrates

I love worm composting (I use red wiggler worms), but wondering how similar or different the *Caenorhabditis elegans* and *Eisenia fetida* are?

Comment: It's possible that the gardening stack exchange might provide better answers if you're interested in their differences in regards to composting.

Comment: @Mys-721tx's answer (excellent, by the way!) is the type of response you'll get here.

Answer (score 1):

*Caenorhabditis elegans* is a nematode. *Eisenia fetida* is an annelid. They both are lophotrochozoans (more specifically, trochozoans).

## Time of Divergence

According to [Michael Lynch](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2640769), there are about 41 amino-acid substitutions per site between Annelida and Nematoda. According to Lynch's data, I estimated that this difference is roughly equal 100 million years.

Therefore, assuming the rate of molecular evolution was constant, their common ancestors lived about 100 million years ago.

## Difference on Anatomy

Nematodes have [pseudocoelom](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_cavity#Pseudocoelom) while annelids have [eucoelom](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coelom). Therefore nematodes do not have a vascular blood system. However, annelids do have one. Nematodes also lack a layer of circular muscle, which annelids have. This layer of muscle allows annelids to move by shorten and elongate their bodies.

*C. elegans* in particular does not have a female gender. There are only male worms and hermaphrodite worms. Only the male can fertilize other worms.

*E. fetida* is hermaphroditic and two of them can fertilize each other.

Comment: The time of divergence within the nematodes is already estimated to be >500 million years http://www.timetree.org/pdf/Blaxter2009Chap28.pdf -- so the divergence of annelids and annelids must be even earlier

Comment: What does "there are about 41 amino-acid substitutions per site" mean?

Comment: @MichaelKuhn It's probably true. Also notice that the Lynch paper was published in 1997, the sequence data he used might simply be not good enough.

Comment: @JackAidley Lynch compared 10 proteins encoded by mitochondrial genes between organisms in 12 phyla. The "substations per site" are the differences in protein sequences coded by homologous genes in two compared organisms.

Comment: @Mys_721tx: I don't see how you can have 41 amino-acid substitutions at a single site between two homologous genes. Surely you can have at most one substitution per site on each gene?

Comment: @JackAidley I think by site Lynch meant the entire gene.